# Parsing JSON response in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, angular-datatables

```
Id  FirstName LastName  Action
1.  Foo       Bar       Edit
2.  Happy     Kid       Edit
```

The **json** which I get from my backend is `[{"id":1,"firstName":"Foo","lastName":"Bar"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Happy","lastName":"Kid"}].`

Below is my HTML file -

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr *ngIf="userList" >
      <td *ngFor="let user of userList">{{user.firstName}}</td>

      <td>
        <button>Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The "userList" holds my json response.

Problem :- I get the error **"Error trying to diff '`[{"id":1,"firstName":"Foo","lastName":"Bar"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Happy","lastName":"Kid"}]`'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed".**

How do I parse my json into my required ui ?

Comment: are u sure that ur list is called itemList not userList ?

Comment: i made a typo ... my list is "userList" !!!

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: Are you sure `userList` is an array? It seems that it might be an unparsed string. Where and how are you creating it?

Answer (score 1):

`ngFor` expects array or object on which it can iterate the result, but as per your problem neither of them is present.

Try using this code -

#### For GET Request -

```
return this.http.get(API_URL)
        .map(res => res.json()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.YOUR_VARIABLE = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => alert(error),
            () => TO_DO_AFTER_REQUEST_COMPLETION
         ));
```

#### For POST Request -

```
return this.http.post(API_URL,POST_PARAMETERS,{
            headers:HEADERS
        })
        .map(res => res.json()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.YOUR_VARIABLE = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => alert(error),
            () => TO_DO_AFTER_REQUEST_COMPLETION
         ));
```

This will return Json response for iteration.

> #### NOTE -
>
> This is a pseudo code, make amendments as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON is invalid. try to keep

```
[{id:1,firstName:"Foo",lastName:"Bar"},{id:2,firstName:"Happy",lastName:"Kid"}]
```

If you want to keep keys as a string you need to write pipe to convert.

Comment: What is invalid about the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The json that you get in this case is just a string and not a javascript array. `ngFor` expects an array to iterate over but the supplied parameter is a string. You need to convert the string to javascript object by using the `json()` method on the response.

Example code:

```
return this.http.get("some-api-url")
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data); // check this line
```

If you are using observables directly and not converting `toPromise`, even then you need to call `json()` method on the response. You can even use the native `JSON.parse` method to convert the string response to javascript object.